# Can You Have 2 Numerical, Identical Values To Represent the nth Percentile?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, standard-deviation, percentile

For an assignment, I am required to find the value of a piece of data in the 70th
percentile using mean and standard deviation.

Here is my organized data in ascending order: `0, 1, -4, 0, -3, 0, -4, -2, 0, 1, -1, 2, 0, -4, 5, -2, 0, 3, -3, 0.`

The image link attached below called `'Percentiles With Normal Distribution'` is the work I have done to find the value. (For some reason I can`t seem to upload the actual image here...)

[Percentiles with Normal Distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkqqM.jpg)

Just in case you cannot access the image, I will explain what I did.

1. I created the normal distribution graph and shaded approximately 70% of it, leaving a little part on the right side empty. `I am finding b, where P(X > b) = p, where p = 0.7`. I reversed this and it is now `P(X > b) = 1 - p (where p = 0.7).` This means to find the (1-p)Th percentile for X.
2. Next, I found the corresponding percentile for Z by looking in the body of the Z-Score Table, and finding the probability that is closest to p = 0.7, to which I did this: `(1-0.7) = 0.3 so the closest value to this is 0.3015, which falls under row = -0.5 and column = 0.02.` This means the `70th percentile for Z is equal to -0.52.`
3. Lastly, I just changed the Z-Score value back into an x-value (original units). `x = Mean + Z(Standard Deviation).` I substiuted my mean value of -0.55, Z-Score value of -0.52, and standard deviation of 2.4 and solved for x. `x = -2.`

Now, if you look at the organized data set I provided above, you`d see that there are two -2`s. This is confusing me because I`m not sure whether there can be two numerical values to represent the value of a certain percentile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three points:

1. If you look at your picture, you want $+0.52$ for the $70$th percentile of a standard normal distribution, but you used $-0.52$ which in fact corresponds to the $30$th percentile.  Correcting this would have given you about $0.7$ rather than $-1.8$
2. There is no problem with a percentile corresponding to a value from the sample which happens multiple times.  For example with the data `3, 5, 5, 5, 7` it is obvious that the $50$th percentile or median is $5$
3. I am not sure why you need to fit a normal distribution unless it is to fit the question's *"using mean and standard deviation"*.  As an alternative, sorting your $20$ data points to `-4, -4, -4, -3, -3, -2, -2, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5`, you have $25\%$ of the values below $-2$ and $65\%$ of the values above $-2$ so you could say $-2$ is the $30$th percentile.  Similarly you have $40\%$ of the values below $0$ and $25\%$ above $0$ so you could say $0$ is the $70$th percentile.

[image]

Comment: This really helps! Thank you! But, is there a mathematical calculation way to prove that 0 is the 70th percentile? My teacher demands mathematical calculations. The way I’ve done it, I’m getting -2.

Comment: @YashviShah: all my comments were mathematical.  You should not be getting $-2$ but about $0.7$ from your calculations.

Comment: To justify $0$ you could draw an empirical cumulative distribution graph perhaps like the one I have added to my answer

Comment: I`m not quite sure how you`re getting 0 as the 70th percentile through the calculations. Did you calculate the same way I did up there? What did you do? I`m trying to get the result of 0 being the 70th percentile. And as for the empirical cumulative distribution graph, I don`t think we learnt that. Is there a way to justify using a normal distribution graph or something?

Comment: Also, I used this link to help me with getting the percentile value using mean and standard deviation - https://www.dummies.com/education/math/statistics/how-to-find-a-percentile-for-a-normal-distribution/